# Problems with initialize Cuckoo

Tags: python, sandbox, cuckoo

I tryed to install last Cuckoo version on my physical machine Windows 10. And I use python 2.7.16. I have Cuckoo installed and its dependencies too, but I cann't initialize it:

```
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\cuckoo.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cuckoo\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cuckoo import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cuckoo\processing\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    __file__, "cuckoo.processing", globals(), Processing
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cuckoo\core\plugins.py", line 46, in enumerate_plugins
    "review its contents and/or validity!" % (module_name, e)
cuckoo.common.exceptions.CuckooOperationalError: Unable to load the Cuckoo plugin at cuckoo.processing.procmemory: cannot import name XOR. Please review its contents and/or validity!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what the problem it was. When there were problems with dependencies, I tryed to install dependencies using command `pip install ...` but it was mistake. For successful installation of the program you should install  [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)